# Div Vertical Align

Tags: vertical-text

Probably one of the most asked questions out there and I've tried several things, with no luck...

Here is a test link for review: http://lifetabernacleaustin.matthewgideon.com/en/welcome/

Basically the header consists of the navigation on the left, which is a fixed width and a column on the right containing text. The right column fills in the rest of the space and the text is centered in that div. The div has a fixed height, but I can not center the text vertically. Line Hight will not work, since the amount of text will be random. Table Cell also does not seem to work, since the width of the right column would be whatever is the remaining space on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with table-cell with the following  CSS definitions:

```
#scripture {
    /* your code */
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}

#scripture p {
    /* your code */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested - vertical looks fine, but as I mentioned - the horizontal centering of the right column no longer works

Comment: You can add `margin: 0 auto` to the #scripture div. That will center the div in the remaining space on the right.

Comment: if you found the answer useful and the solution working, then please accept the answer so other people can find it, too.

Answer (score 0):

See [Vertically align text in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Add

```
display: table-cell;
```

to the div#scripture CSS.

Probably best to add it in style.css, since the other stylesheets only apply at certain screen widths.

[image]

Comment: tried that, but then it eliminates the text being centered between the left column and the far right of the browser window.

Comment: I only see a difference in the vertical when I make that change.  It's not perfectly centered, but it wasn't before either.

Comment: Tried what you suggested - vertical looks fine, but as I mentioned - the horizontal centering of the right column no longer works